# Remix IDE: How can I open a file from GitHub repository ID

Tags: remix

I want to compile and use a smart contract located in a GitHub repository on a specific branch or compile ID. I did it the same thing in the past but I've always used a URL which prompted the Git ID as a pop-up.

I can't recall the URL and I don't see the open from git id option within Remix.

Can anyone point me on the right direction?

Thanks on advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Got the URL just digging around my browser history:

https://remix.ethereum.org/#gist=&optimize=false